# Use one list to order another Excel

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I need to sort column C in the same order as column A.  Best method to go about it?  The list on column A is sorted by the number of fields that aren't empty in those accompanying columns.    I realize in that small snippet the numbers aren't shared among both lists, but the entire list is >30,000 rows.

Comment: Are the exact same numbers in both column A and C?  Do you mean you need to sort colc **and the other columns** ?  You could insert a column of fomulas using `MATCH(colCvalue,colAlist,0)` to find the position of each value in colC in the list in ColA: copy/pastevalues then sort on that new column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using the match function. So in C1 enter:

```
=Match($B1,$A:$A,0)
```

That should find the first matching value in column A (I am assuming there is a unique match). Then you can select both of columns B and C and sort by column C. This way B will be sorted by A. See the help for the match function if there is not exactly one match in A for every value in B (though I'm not sure this will help, frankly, I've had a couple of drinks..).

Comment: No need to specify rows if you want to just use the whole column, this also makes the formula more compatible with all Excel versions:  **=MATCH($B1, $A:$A, 0)**